# Audio does not play properly when skipped to a time in Firefox - HTML 5 <audio>

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, audio, position

I am working on a project where it is required to skip to a particular time, triggered by a click event. I am using audio.js and html5 'audio' tag. This worked fine in other browsers, but in firefox, the audio gets stuck:

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LRW3U/

Javascript:

```
$('h1').click(function(){
audiojs.events.ready(function() {
    var as = audiojs.createAll({
        css: false,
        preload: true,

    });
    audio = as[0];
});
$('audio').bind('canplaythrough', function () {
   $(this)[0].currentTime = 10;
  audio.play();
});
```

})

HTML

```
<h1>Play</h1>
<audio src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Tromboon-sample.ogg" preload controls />
```

Again this happens only in firefox!

Please help!

Comment: Ive been struggling with this also - have a look at this question, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911175/html5-audio-starts-from-the-wrong-position-in-firefox

Comment: No problem with Firefox 24.6.0 under Linux