# How to set position correctly in SoundJS for Firefox, IE

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, createjs, soundjs

I'm trying to use [SoundJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS) to play sn mp3 file and seek to a specific position.  I'm using:

```
instance.setPosition(10000);
```

which works correctly in Google Chrome.  But in Mozilla Firefox I hear the sound playing from the correct position, and a second instance of the sound also playing from another position.

In Internet Explorer, the sound starts playing again from the beginning.

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpickard/qHJth/) (with autoplaying sound) and here is the complete javascript:

```
createjs.Sound.registerPlugins([createjs.WebAudioPlugin, createjs.HTMLAudioPlugin, createjs.FlashPlugin]);
createjs.Sound.addEventListener("fileload", handleLoad);
createjs.Sound.registerSound("http://ivdemo.chaseits.co.uk/enron/20050204-4026(7550490)a.mp3", "sound");

function handleLoad(event) {
    var instance = createjs.Sound.play("sound");
    var ten = document.getElementById('ten-secs');
    ten.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        instance.setPosition(10000);
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong for Firefox and IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I commented on in your other question, there was a bug with in a previous version of SoundJS which should be fixed in the [latest available on github](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS).  You can test this behavior yourself with the [TestSuite example](http://www.createjs.com/#!/SoundJS/demos/testSuite).

Nice use of jsfiddle to demonstrate the issue, by the by.

Hope that helps.